# How to do a lotto program without using loops and array statements?

Tags: java

Our professor tasked us to create a lotto program that will generate 6 random numbers ranging from 1-55 without us using the arrays and loops, we can only use "if else" statements. We also have to put scanner in which the user/better will input his 6 numbers also ranging from 1-55. The user's numbers should win as long as the 6 of the numbers match regardless of arrangements. For example

```
User: 1,2,3,4,5,6
Random Number:6,3,4,2,1,5
System: You Win!
```

I created a lotto program but my program requires every numbers to match with regards to their arrangement

```
User: 1,2,3,4,5,6
Random:6,5,4,3,2,1 
System: You Lose
```

I don't have any idea how to ignore the arrangements. I tried search for a lot of thing in the internet and they mostly use arrays and loops.

Comment: An array can easily be replaced by just using lots of separate variables. So instead of `userNumber[]` to save the numbers the user inputs just use `userNumber1`, `userNumber2` etc. pp.

Comment: At the very least you can add your current code to the question. How are you generating 6 different random numbers without arrays and loops?

Comment: `if ((userinput1 == system1 || userinput1 == system2 || userinput1 == system3 || …) && (userinput2 == system1 || userinput2 == system2 || …`

Comment: *You Win!* Not very likely is it?

Comment: If we can assume that the random numbers are distinct, you can write a function which compares a single number to each of them, return true if any match, then call that once for each guess and and the results together.

Comment: Perhaps he wants you to use recursion?

Comment: It sounds like a lot of busy work, at the end is he going to be "see how much easier it is to use arrays".

Comment: you can sort both arrays and compare numbers one by one

Comment: @dimirsenZ: note that the question is explicitly about not using arrays.

Comment: Ok. Sort the list or whichever else collection you deal with and compare the elements one after one

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class LottoGame {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Input 6 numbers [1-55] separated with space: ");
        NumberSet userNumberSet = new NumberSet();
        userNumberSet.a = new AtomicInteger(scan.nextInt());
        userNumberSet.b = new AtomicInteger(scan.nextInt());
        userNumberSet.c = new AtomicInteger(scan.nextInt());
        userNumberSet.d = new AtomicInteger(scan.nextInt());
        userNumberSet.e = new AtomicInteger(scan.nextInt());
        userNumberSet.f = new AtomicInteger(scan.nextInt());

        System.out.format("User: %d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n", userNumberSet.a.get(), userNumberSet.b.get(),
                          userNumberSet.c.get(), userNumberSet.d.get(), userNumberSet.e.get(), userNumberSet.f.get());

        userNumberSet.sort();

        NumberSet randomNumberSet = getRandomNumberSet();

        System.out.format("Randome Number: %d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n", randomNumberSet.a.get(), randomNumberSet.b.get(),
                          randomNumberSet.c.get(), randomNumberSet.d.get(), randomNumberSet.e.get(),
                          randomNumberSet.f.get());

        randomNumberSet.sort();

        boolean win = userNumberSet.a.get() == randomNumberSet.a.get();
        win &= userNumberSet.b.get() == randomNumberSet.b.get();
        win &= userNumberSet.c.get() == randomNumberSet.c.get();
        win &= userNumberSet.d.get() == randomNumberSet.d.get();
        win &= userNumberSet.e.get() == randomNumberSet.e.get();
        win &= userNumberSet.f.get() == randomNumberSet.f.get();

        System.out.println("System: " + (win ? "You Win!" : "You Lose"));
    }

    private static NumberSet getRandomNumberSet() {
        Random random = new Random();
        NumberSet numberSet = new NumberSet();
        numberSet.a = new AtomicInteger(random.nextInt(55) + 1);
        numberSet.b = new AtomicInteger(random.nextInt(55) + 1);
        numberSet.c = new AtomicInteger(random.nextInt(55) + 1);
        numberSet.d = new AtomicInteger(random.nextInt(55) + 1);
        numberSet.e = new AtomicInteger(random.nextInt(55) + 1);
        numberSet.f = new AtomicInteger(random.nextInt(55) + 1);
        return numberSet;
    }

    private static final class NumberSet {

        private AtomicInteger a;
        private AtomicInteger b;
        private AtomicInteger c;
        private AtomicInteger d;
        private AtomicInteger e;
        private AtomicInteger f;

        public void sort() {
            sort(a, b);
            sort(b, c);
            sort(c, d);
            sort(d, e);
            sort(e, f);
        }

        private void sort(AtomicInteger one, AtomicInteger two) {
            if (one.get() > two.get()) {
                int tmp = one.get();
                one.set(two.get());
                two.set(tmp);
            }

            if (two == b) {
                sort(one, c);
            } else if (two == c) {
                sort(one, d);
            } else if (two == d) {
                sort(one, e);
            } else if (two == e) {
                sort(one, f);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

***P.S.** I think you are able to update a bit this snippte to check that `NumberSet` contains only unique numbers.*

Comment: @tgdavies would you do this with an array? Maybe they're supposed to use a Set, and that is why the professor said not to use an array, use a better data structure.